# Why steel coils are called Wire rod?

Tags: rolling

From google, I got this meaning of Wire rod:

> Wire rod is a long steel semi-finished product manufactured by hot
> rolling billets on  continuous rolling mills.

Here is the stack of steel coils:

[image]

Why steel coils are called Wire rod?

Comment: I wonder if you cut the ties would your question be answered? What diameter is a "rod".

Comment: So coils of steel wire. A rod can be an actuator or bar but terminology depends on use.

Comment: Quiet possible because it's made as a long rod that gets wound into a coil for ease of storage & transportation.

Answer (score 1):

Standard industry terminology . Ingots, blooms , billets , wire bar ,wire rod ( to 4' diameter) , sheets ( flat stock up to 1.5 " thick as I remember) . Probably better for you to learn the terminology than try to straighten out the industry .

Answer (score 0):

It's an arbitrary designation. Wire is smaller in diameter than rod, rod is smaller than bar and bar is smaller than billet.

In general, steel stock thinner than *rod* can be shipped from the mill in *coils* and then easily straightened at the point of use. You cannot do that with anything thicker than *wire*.